Log-Linearization in Calvo Pricing
Can anyone please provide a step by step derivation of the log-linearized form of the following equation. I've tried to get from the first equation to the second but to no avail. I'm really struggling.

There is a typo in your (B.2.4). I believe the right-hand side should include a $P_{T,t-1}^H$ term. That is, it should be $P_{T,t}^H=\left[\theta_T (P_{T,t-1})^{1-\varepsilon}+(1-\theta_T)(\bar{P}_{T,t}^H)^{1-\varepsilon}\right]^{\frac{1}{1-\varepsilon}}$. Divide this expression by $P_{T,t-1}^H$ to get $$\frac{P_{T,t}^H}{P_{T,t-1}^H}=\left[\theta_T+(1-\theta_T)\left(\frac{\bar{P}_{T,t}^H}{P_{T,t-1}^H}\right)^{1-\varepsilon}\right]^{\frac{1}{1-\varepsilon}}$$ Taking the exponent to the other side, $$\left(\frac{P_{T,t}^H}{P_{T,t-1}^H}\right)^{1-\varepsilon}=\theta_T+(1-\theta_T)\left(\frac{\bar{P}_{T,t}^H}{P_{T,t-1}^H}\right)^{1-\varepsilon}$$
Log-linearisation then proceeds like (with tildes indicating steady-state values), $$\begin{align*} 0&=\theta_T+(1-\theta_T)\left(\frac{\bar{P}_{T,t}^H}{P_{T,t-1}^H}\right)^{1-\varepsilon}-\left(\frac{P_{T,t}^H}{P_{T,t-1}^H}\right)^{1-\varepsilon} \\
&=\theta_T+(1-\theta_T) \left[\widetilde{\left(\frac{\bar{P}_{T,t}^H}{P_{T,t-1}^H}\right)}^{1-\varepsilon}\right]\exp\{(1-\varepsilon)(\bar{p}_{T,t}^H-p_{T,t-1}^H)\}- \left[\widetilde{\left(\frac{P_{T,t}^H}{P_{T,t-1}^H}\right)}^{1-\varepsilon}\right]\exp\{(1-\varepsilon)\pi_{T,t}^H\} \\
&\approx \underbrace{\theta_T+(1-\theta_T) \left[\widetilde{\left(\frac{\bar{P}_{T,t}^H}{P_{T,t-1}^H}\right)}^{1-\varepsilon}\right] -\left[\widetilde{\left(\frac{P_{T,t}^H}{P_{T,t-1}^H}\right)}^{1-\varepsilon}\right]}_{=0}+\dots\\
& \qquad \qquad \dots+(1-\varepsilon)\left[(1-\theta_T)(\bar{p}_{T,t}^H-p_{T,t-1}^H)\left[\widetilde{\left(\frac{\bar{P}_{T,t}^H}{P_{T,t-1}^H}\right)}^{1-\varepsilon}\right]-\pi_{T,t}^H\left[\widetilde{\left(\frac{P_{T,t}^H}{P_{T,t-1}^H}\right)}^{1-\varepsilon}\right]\right] \end{align*}$$
Therefore, $$\pi_{T,t}^H\left[\widetilde{\left(\frac{P_{T,t}^H}{P_{T,t-1}^H}\right)}^{1-\varepsilon}\right] =(1-\theta_T)(\bar{p}_{T,t}^H-p_{T,t-1}^H)\left[\widetilde{\left(\frac{\bar{P}_{T,t}^H}{P_{T,t-1}^H}\right)}^{1-\varepsilon}\right]$$
In steady state, $\left[\widetilde{\left(\frac{P_{T,t}^H}{P_{T,t-1}^H}\right)}^{1-\varepsilon}\right]=\left[\widetilde{\left(\frac{\bar{P}_{T,t}^H}{P_{T,t-1}^H}\right)}^{1-\varepsilon}\right]=1$. So, our expression simplifies to the desired one: $$\pi_{T,t}^H =(1-\theta_T)(\bar{p}_{T,t}^H-p_{T,t-1}^H)$$

Thank you so much Joseph for the answer. Really appreciate the help.

@GoldmanClarck No problem! I realised after looking again that there is a typo in the (B.2.4) equation you stated which may have been what made the derivation difficult. I have edited my answer to account for this.

You are absolutely right! Thank you.
